# Dynamical SUMIF command

Tags: excel, sum, conditional-statements

If it is possible, I'd like to create a formula that will allow me the following:

Formula must be in the entire column or in this example, in the range B1:B5. The formula is based on a condition, that when the total sum of cells from column A is lower D1, than it gives "X". If the total sum is over D1, then it gives an empty field - "".

In this example the total sum of the cells, that are over D1 value is in the first 3 rows, hence the three X-es, and then it stops.

[image: Valid XHTML]
<sub>(source: [shrani.si](http://shrani.si/f/1W/10N/4cuGrhGd/delete.png))</sub>
.

I presume it would be possible to do this with multiple SUMIF commands, but does anyone know a smoother solution for this?

Thanks!

Comment: Why does **B3** have an **x** ?  20+50+70 exceeds 100.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent The plan is to stop with "X" with the first row when the sum is over 100, here this happens in B3. It can stop when the simple condition is met, e.g. 20+50+... <100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily by using an absolute reference for the starting point of a `SUM` and using a relative reference for the end point.  When copied down, this formulas works fine.

```
=IF(SUM($A$1:A1)<$D$1,"x","")
```

**Results**

[image: sum results]

Comment: Thanks, works great! Bit ashamed i didn't come up to this by myself.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=IF(SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,0,$A$1:A1,1))>$D$1,"X","")
```

This formula should start at B1 and then you use auto-increment to populate other cells

Comment: I cant figure out why, but it doesnt work. Smth needs to be fixed in the OFFSET command